# Firebase Cloud Messaging Cannot read property 'receiver_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications. When I want to send friend request in my Android app the other client doesn't receive a notification about this. And Firebase Functions log says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiver_id' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:9:35)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:109:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:139:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:730:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Here is JavaScript code:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite(event => {
  const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;

  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification to send to: ', receiver_id);

  if (!event.data.val) {
    return console.log('A notification has been deleted from database: ', notification_id);
  }

  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');

  return deviceToken.then(result => {
    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload = {
      notification:
      {
        title: "Friend Request",
        body: "you have received a new friend request",
        icon: "default"
      }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
      console.log('This was the notification feature.');
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification : ', user_id);

const afterData = change.after.val();

if (!afterData){
    return null;
}

const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;


    console.log('You have a new notification from: ', from_user_id);

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result => {

        const token_id = result.val();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "New Friend Request",
                body: "You've received a new Friend Request",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
            console.log('This was the notification feature');
        });

    });

});

});
```

Try this code. It is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877553/function-returned-undefined-expected-promise-or-value-firebase-log-error) uploaded by @xxxQDAxxx.